# trying to split sentence into according to below output requirement

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to break sentence while values find from array2 and sentence push into new array and also push space where values find from array2.

I want output cloud be like this

```
Arr=["I want to eat", "","", and, "" ]
```

```
let str = "I want to eat Banana Apple and Mango";
var array1 = str.split(" ");
var array2 = ["Banana", "Apple","Mango", "hut", "gut"];

const res = array1.map((item) =>  array2.includes(item) ? "" : item);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: What is the problem? You code looks ok according to what you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Break sentence according to array values and push into another array using javscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68000309/break-sentence-according-to-array-values-and-push-into-another-array-using-javsc)

Answer (score 0):

okay so here the output will be like  `[ 'I want to eat', '', '', 'and', '' ]` and this is what you want.

```js
let str = "I want to eat Banana Apple and Mango";

var array1 = str.split(" ") 
var array2 = ["Banana", "Apple","Mango", "hut", "gut"];

const res = []
var temp = ""
array1.forEach(word => {
    if(!array2.includes(word)){
        temp += word + ' ';
    }else{
        if(temp !== "") res.push(temp)
        res.push("")
        temp = ""
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```js
let str = "I want to eat Banana Apple and Mango";
const array2 = ["Banana", "Apple","Mango", "hut", "gut"];
const separator = "|";

array2.forEach(item => {
str = str.replaceAll(item, separator)
})

let result = str.split(separator).map(item => item.trim());
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know what is the first index of your result array, you can initialize it with the required value.

```
let str = 'I want to eat Banana Apple and Mango';
let arr1 = str.split(' ');
let fruits = ["Banana", "Apple","Mango", "hut", "gut"];
let res = ['I want to eat']; // initialize it with known value

// start the loop from the values from where you are interested.
for (let i = 4; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (fruits.includes(arr1[i])) {
        res.push('');
    } else {
        res.push(arr1[i]);
    }
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a little different with this because you're continually adding to a previous iteration. `forEach` takes care of it, so would `reduce()`

```js
let str = "I want to eat Banana Apple and Mango";
var array1 = str.split(" ");
var array2 = ["Banana", "Apple","Mango", "hut", "gut"];
stra = [""];
array1.forEach(e => {
if (array2.includes(e)) { stra.push(''); return; }
let i = stra.length-1 ;
stra[i] += " " + e
})
stra = stra.map(e => e.trim());
console.log(stra)

let reduce = array1.reduce((b,a) => {
if (array2.includes(a)) b.push('');
else {
let i = b.length-1 ;
b[i] += " " + a
}
return b;
},['']).map(e=>e.trim());

console.log(reduce)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the below code could help:

```js
let str = "I want to eat Banana Apple and Mango";
var array1 = str.split(" ");
var array2 = ["Banana", "Apple", "Mango", "hut", "gut"];

const res = array1.reduce((accumulator, currentVal, i) => {
  const itemExist = array2.includes(currentVal);
  const lastIndex = accumulator.length - 1;
  if(i !== 0 && !itemExist && accumulator[lastIndex]) {
    accumulator[lastIndex] = accumulator[lastIndex] + " " + currentVal;
  } else {
    accumulator.push(itemExist ? "" : currentVal);
  }
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Check [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for more details on how to use reduce.